# unable to use wifi on sony vaio duo 13 SVD13215CGB

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom, vaio

I'm new to linux and I've recently installed ubuntu 15.04 onto my 16GB thumbdrive. The issue is that it has no wifi capability.

lspci shows:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
```

lshw:

```
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: wwan0
       serial: f2:71:5c:26:ae:cf
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=qmi_wwan driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=WWAN/QMI device link=no multicast=yes
```

On my windows, I see that it uses a broadcom driver. I've tried the solution from [cannot use wifi broadcom 802.11 alternative driver in ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632907/cannot-use-wifi-broadcom-802-11-alternative-drive-in-ubuntu-15-04) , to no avail. There were no error message, it appears as if nothing has changed.

Btw, I have no internet access on my linux since it cannot connect to wifi, and I'm also using an ethernet to usb adapter for ethernet connection, which I do not have the driver (QF9700).

Would appreciate any help to get my wifi working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution for 15.04, but I've installed 14.04 instead and followed the answer from https://askubuntu.com/a/465502/424825 and got the wireless working.

Note: I mentioned that it's not a solution for 15.04 because none of the answers from the link that I've posted worked when I was still on 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system > Administration > Additional Drivers/Hardware Drivers.

It will fetch the Broadcom drivers for your wifi. Select and install it. And Reboot the system

Comment: I don't see any options for installing any drivers. Actually, I cannot even navigate to the Additional Drivers/Hardware Drivers that you have mentioned. I am assuming that this window is the same as the Additional Drivers/Hardware Drivers that you've mentioned.

<img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/33o35a0.png" width="100" height="100">